# ASP.NET Identity library - delete user does not delete their claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am using the ASP.NET Core Identity library in Blazor server side version 8.

The library provides a page for a user to delete themselves from the system. When they are deleted - it does not delete any claims they have.

How can I have it delete any associated claims?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ASP.NET Identity library - delete user does not delete their claims
>
> The library provides a page for a user to delete themselves from the
> system. When they are deleted - it does not delete any claims they
> have.

It would have been nicer if you could share your existing code how you were trying to delete the user.

Becuase, In ASP.NET Core Identity, when you delete a user, the associated claims are not automatically deleted by default. If you want to delete the claims along with the user, you can override the default behavior by extending the [UserManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

> How can I have it delete any associated claims?

In order to remove user claims first we need to inject the `UserManager` service, where we have [RemoveClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.removeclaim?view=net-8.0) which actually removes the claims.

Then, we have to retrieve the user's claims, delete them individually using a loop, and finally delete the user – this ensures all associated claims are removed when a user gets deleted in your ASP.NET Core Identity application.

Remember to configure `UserManager` properly and consider performance and data integrity for large volumes of claims.

Let's have a look how we can implement that in practice:

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager

var userId = 123;
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(userId);
foreach (var claim in claims)
{
    await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(userId, claim);
}

await _userManager.DeleteAsync(userId);
```

**Note:** As said earlier, claims deletion must be executed before removing user and make sure to replace `IdentityUser` class with your actual user type if you have a custom user class. In addition, please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.removeclaim?view=net-8.0) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is the approach I figured I have to implement. But don't you find it surprising that the library allows orphan claims to remain in the database?

Comment: Yes sir, the both side are valid. Because,  according to convention, Microsoft said in document, we don't remove claims by default  the caller have to delete it before removing the user itself which is valid. On the other side, yeah its kind of orphan claims because while I am calling delete user so it should remove all the related stuff to erase as well.